# Showing black screen when recording a video using camera in iOS 14.2

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture, ios14, xcode12

In my application, I written a code to record a video using UIImagePickerController. It is absolutely working fine with all other devices, only one of my client have an issue with iPhone 8 running iOS 14.2 that while recording video, it shows black screen and no swipe working for front or rear camera on right bottom button.

Here is my code and Image:

```
UIImagePickerController *evidencePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
evidencePicker.delegate = self;
evidencePicker.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
evidencePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
evidencePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0;
evidencePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
evidencePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:evidencePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: Black screen on camera for video]

Camera permission is also given.

So, am I doing anything wrong to present UIImagePickerController? Or something else needs to check?

Answer (score 0):

Before presenting UIImagePickerController check for availability of camera. Something like this:

```
[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]
```

Comment: outside of your application, is the user able to capture video? We had one device iPhone 7, which has an issue with the native camera app.

Comment: Native camera works fine. The issue is from my application and for iPhone 8 device only.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, my device is 14.3.
My colleague's is 14.6 , the same code 14.6 is normal. I tested it is UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera this enumeration value problem, if you change it to the default will be able to record video normally